# asio "std::error_code" not resolved in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, boost-asio

I am completely newbie at ASIO c++ socket library. Manage to set up in eclipse with 'asio nonboost' and openssl library.
Now I am stuck on "std::error_code" not resolved.

Please assist, I had already west lots of time on this.

Following is the async_udp_echo_server page from asio I am trying to run.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "asio.hpp"

using asio::ip::udp;

class server
{
public:
  server(asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))
  {
    do_receive();
  }

  void do_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd)
        {
          if (!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
          {
            do_send(bytes_recvd);
          }
          else
          {
            do_receive();
          }
        });
  }

  void do_send(std::size_t length)
  {
    socket_.async_send_to(
        asio::buffer(data_, length), sender_endpoint_,
        [this](std::error_code /*ec*/, std::size_t /*bytes_sent*/)
        {
          do_receive();
        });
  }

private:
  udp::socket socket_;
  udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_udp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    asio::io_service io_service;

    server s(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `error_code` is in `std`? (Hint: It's in `boost::system`)

Comment: @tkausl asio can be used in standalone mode. In this case, it uses std::error_code

Comment: Uh, didn't knew that. In this case, he'd need to include `system_error` tough.

Comment: Thanks, I tried #include <system_error> but no luck.

Comment: Is your error that it is not defined, or is it a linking error (unresolved external symbol)? Can you show the precise error?

Comment: Show us your build command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using "standalone" `asio`, `error_code` should be `asio::error_code` not `std::error_code`. Note: `boost::system::error_code` is required by `boost::asio`.

I use the following macros to switch between `boost` and "standalone" `asio`:

```
#ifdef ASIO_STANDALONE
  #include <asio.hpp>
  #define ASIO asio
  #define ASIO_ERROR_CODE asio::error_code
  #define ASIO_TIMER asio::steady_timer
#else
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>
  #define ASIO boost::asio
  #define ASIO_ERROR_CODE boost::system::error_code
  #define ASIO_TIMER boost::asio::deadline_timer
#endif
```